# What is meant by Remote Diuretics & Remote Vomiting?

Tags: medicine

I have encountered the terms **Remote Diuretics** & **Remote Vomiting** separately or sometimes in association in various articles related to medicine.

But I am unable to find any reference to what they actually mean.

Can you help me understand these terms please?

**Update**

Examples:

> Urine sodium less than 10 mmol/L indicates extrarenal loss of urine
>   (remote diuretic use and remote vomiting).

link: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK470386/

[image]

Go to google and search for "remote diuretic" to get more references, some are:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some context such as a citation.

Comment: @BryanKrause i have updated the post

Answer (score 1):

"Remote" can [mean distant/far away, often in space but also in time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remote) (as in, the "remote past"). In just the search results you included in your question it is fairly clear that these sources are using the word "remote" to mean (relatively)"far away in time" or simply "not recent."

For example:

> associated with remote diuretic use, therefore, diuretic effects were already washed off

Referring to diuretic use in the past, so there is not current diuretic effect but the secondary consequences are still present.

Note that these terms are quite uncommon in the literature, I get 21 results in Google Scholar for "remote diuretic" and 16 for "remote vomiting" and nearly all seem to be related to the specific context of hypokalemia.